# How do I get rid of the AWS CloudWatch agent from my server?

Tags: aws, bitnami

When using htop, I can see this process:

```
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent
```

I don't need the cloudwatch agent on this server, how do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: That's the thing, I don't remember installing this

Answer (score 4):

For anyone with the same issue -

```
sudo apt remove amazon-cloudwatch-agent
```

Comment: besto ever, thank you. even in AWS docs didn't say this lol